# Databinding to a different window

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

In my WPF application I have a main windown with a canvas and a few sliders.

Inside this canvas there are multiple versions of a custom UserControl.  The user control is very basic, just and image and a textblock.  I want to bind the text size of the textblock inside the user controls to one of my sliders in the main window.

I have no idea how to point the binding to a different window!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a view model? If yes, you can create a property in the view model with change notification and bind it to the parent windows slider and the same to the user controllers text block properties.

Answer (score 0):

create a dependency property in your usercontrol and bind your slider value to it.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to "dial out" from the user control to point to the main window slider...